# MySQL vs Microsoft SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, comparison

I've been learning Microsoft Access 2007 in a computer class at college and see that it's a very powerful database program... I realize that it might not be the same as a web server database, but I was thinking about switching to MSSQL.

What are the biggest differences between MySQL and MSSQL?  Does MS have any pros or cons that My might not have?  How would one benefit me more than the other?

Answer (score 3):

I have used extensively MS SQL Server. The main difference is MS SQL Server works only with Windows platform. MySQL works with all platforms. MySQL is open source and now bought by Oracle, so no one knows the fate of MySQL. If you working with .NET or Windows platform, I would suggest working with MS SQL, else the obvious choice is MySQL. LAMP uses MySQL. Big companies like Facebook uses LAMP and hence MySQL. Many banks like Chase use .NET and hence mostly MS SQL Server. If you are a Windows fan, go for MS SQL server. If you are a guy who believes in Open source, go for MySQL.

Comment: MSAccess is a desktop database, so there are more differences than just this.  The MSAccess database engine is more akin to SQLite or Firebird

Comment: If you're worried about the future of MySQL under Oracle, you can use [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/) as a drop-in replacement for MySQL. It's developed by the original developers of MySQL.

Comment: You don't know the fate of anything, but with mysql being Open Source/Free Software, the risks are much lower. It does not matter what oracle does, someone else can take over.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a complete comparision in [mysql and mssql](http://swik.net/MySQL/MySQL+vs+MS+SQL+Server) here. They have completely described each and every thing

Comment: Except that they're comparing the relatively recent MySQL 5.0 with MS SQL Server 2000. That is a problem, especially considering that SQL Server 2005 was a major overhaul that introduced a lot of changes to the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Both platforms are good to learn on but it probably will come down to preference and what it is you want your database to do. MySQL comparatively is a much simpler product in terms of extra features but still manages to be a powerfull plateform especially when you compare it to access.

From a development standpoint MS SQL is going to have a much richer version of SQL where MySQL is going to have a much more basic version of SQL. The Management Studio that comes with MS SQL as well is also an advantage over MySQL - although there are some other ones you can download to interact with MySQL.

From an administrative/implementation/server side in terms of extras MS SQL is going to win hands down with the rich High Availability features (edition depending) as well all the other little bits and pieces that come packaged with the system MySQL just cant compare to what comes packaged natively.

It is likely going to come down to personal preference though and what it is you want to build. MySQL rules on the web and linux fronts but really lacks a lot of advanced functionality that comes with MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your end goal is. If it's preparing for a job then I suggest exposing yourself to both so that you're familiar and in doing so you hopefully will be able to find which one you have a preference and from there you can start to focus on that particular version to improve your skills and develop experience. Regardless though I would recommend getting familiar with both. My job uses MS SQL but I just got a consulting gig doing MySQL and I keep getting caught up on small differences - it's frustrating. Wish I'd seen it before in college.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the differences in SQL syntax between MSSQL and MySQL

In MSSQL the table names and column names are enclosed in double quotes or square brackets whereas in MySQL table names and column names are enclosed in backtick (“`”)  character

Example

MSSQL
CREATE TABLE "Employees" ("Empno"  VARCHAR(10),"EmpName" Varchar(100) ......

SELECT [Empno],[EmpName] from "Employees" ......
MySQL
CREATE TABLE `Employees` (`Empno` VARCHAR(10),`EmpName` Varchar(100) ......

SELECT `Empno`,`EmpName` from `Employees` ......

Enclosing identifier names in enclosing character is optional in both database softwares, but if the identifier name contains blank spaces then it becomes mandatory to enclose it within double quotes or square brackets.

For Example the following statement can be written like this

MSSQL
CREATE TABLE "Employees" ("Empno"  VARCHAR(10),"EmpName" Varchar(100) ......
MySQL
CREATE TABLE `Employees` (`Empno` VARCHAR(10),`EmpName` Varchar(100) ......
or without enclosing character like this.

MSSQL
CREATE TABLE Employees (Empno  VARCHAR(10),EmpName Varchar(100) ......

MySQL
CREATE TABLE Employees (Empno  VARCHAR(10),EmpName Varchar(100) ......

but if the identitfier name contains blank spaces then you have to enclosed it with double quotes or square brackets

MSSQL
CREATE TABLE "Employees Table" ("Emp No"  VARCHAR(10),"EmpName" Varchar(100) ......

MySQL
CREATE TABLE `Employees Table` (`Emp No` VARCHAR(10),`EmpName` Varchar(100) ......

you can't  write it like this

MSSQL
CREATE TABLE Employees Table (Emp No  VARCHAR(10),EmpName Varchar(100) ......

MySQL
CREATE TABLE Employees Table (Emp No VARCHAR(10),EmpName Varchar(100) ......

In MySQL if you turn on ANSI_QUOTES  SQL mode option with the following command

mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';

then MySQL also allows to quote identifiers within double quotation marks. But remember when you enable this option you cannot quote literal strings in double quotes in SQL statements. you have to use only single quotes for quoting  literal strings in SQL statements

Case Sensitive
In MS SQL if a database is created with Case Sensitive COLLATION then table names and column names are case sensitive otherwise, if the database is created with a Case Insensitive Collation then identifier names are case insensitive

For Example

If you created a table in Case Sensitive Collation database, like this

create table Employee (SNo int,Name Varchar(100),Sal money)
Notice the captial E in tablename

Then if you give the following command

select * from employee
It will give error