# mysql to sql server

Tags: vb6-migration

before i am using mysql and now using sql server, does it have the same syntax?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The basic syntax is the same "SQL" standard, but a lot of stuff is not. For example in MySQL you'd write .. LIMTIT 0,3 .. while in MSSQL you have to use the TOP syntax.

You're best off with it if you use a Database abastraction layer. This may help you too:
http://www.tometasoftware.com/MySQL-5-vs-Microsoft-SQL-Server-2005.asp

[MySQL vs Microsoft SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176940/mysql-vs-microsoft-sql)

Comment: himoidaschl
may i know if the 'if statement' usage is also different to sql server, can you give me an example?

Comment: jeah there seems to be a slight difference: MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html and MSSQL http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showpost.php?s=e6ab0d5ad49989bb50168129017e32a8&p=1718558&postcount=3

Comment: thanks, ill try again to debug my code, thanks for the help :)

Comment: if this has helped you, you may mark this question as "answered"! :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL uses ANSI and ISO standards.  You may find that you'll need to change a few queries where you are using MySQL specific keywords like `LIMIT` for example.